# Assign fields to variables - Bash

Tags: bash, unix

Suppose I have a string with pipe separator:

```
str="1|2|3|4"
```

I want them to be assigned to specific variables.

```
var_a=1
var_b=2
var_c=3
var_d=4
```

I am doing it in this way:

```
var_a="`echo $str | cut -d'|' -f1`"
var_b="`echo $str | cut -d'|' -f2`"
var_c="`echo $str | cut -d'|' -f3`"
var_d="`echo $str | cut -d'|' -f4`"
```

Can this be done in an efficient way? Please suggest.

Comment: Would it be ok to use an array instead of five different variables?

Comment: BTW, `echo $str` is itself buggy; `echo "$str"` is slightly better (won't replace a `*` with a list of filenames, for example); `printf '%s\n' "$str"` is *much* better (works correctly with all possible values, including `-n` or `-e`, which some versions of `echo` will consume). See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX `echo` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use an array to store individual delimited values:

```
str="1|2|3|4"
IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< "$str"

#examine array values
declare -p arr
```

```
declare -a arr='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")'
```

To loop through array, use:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: That's fair assuming the OP really wants to read a completely variable number of items. I'm not sure we know that's the case, vs four specific fields having distinct meanings.

Comment: Yes, I just suggested an alternative assuming variable number of delimited values in input.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use array for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

```
IFS='|' read -r var_a var_b var_c var_d rest <<<"$str"
```

`rest` is the variable that gets further columns after the first four, should any others exist. If you just want to discard them, the conventional name to use for a placeholder variable is `_`.

This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #1: *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Awesome one-liner